# Zend2 framework modules.config.php modules (Zend /form, /db, not loading)

Tags: php, zend-framework

I´m having problem with zend2 framework get started application. Im getting error

```
Uncaught exception 'Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Module (Zend\Form) could not be initialized
```

In config/modules.config.php i do have

```
return [
'Zend\Form',
'Zend\Db',
'Zend\Router',
'Zend\Validator',
'Application',
'Album',
];
```

If i delete Zend\Form i get same problem with Zend\Db

```
Uncaught exception 'Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Module (Zend\Db) could not be initialized.'
```

Of course i do need both of those modules... I just wanted to show you that its not bug only in Zend\Form... It looks like these modules are not loading.

Comment: Sorry for asking, i figured that out i needed to install packages using composer. Command is:composer require zendframework/zend-db, same with form: composer require zendframework/zend-form